# Error: Cannot call value of non-function type '[JSONObject]'

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to update an object with JSON data.  That data is returned in a completion block after it has been parsed.  When I try and return it I get the error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type '[JSONObject]'

Here is my function:

```
  static func updateResultsDictionary(urlExtension: String, completion: [JSONObject]){

    var jsonDataArray = [JSONObject]()

    let nm = NetworkManager.sharedManager

    _ = nm.getJSONData(urlExtension: urlExtension, completion: {data in

      if let jsonDictionary = nm.parseJSONFromData(data) {

        let resultDictionaries = jsonDictionary["result"] as! [[String : Any]]
        for resultsDictionary in resultDictionaries {// enumerate through dictionary
          let jsonInfo = JSONObject(resultsDictionary: resultsDictionary)

          jsonDataArray.append(jsonInfo)

        }
      }
    })

   completion(jsonDataArray) //The error happens here
  }
```

EDIT: After changing

> completion: [JSONObject]

to

> completion: @escaping ([JSONObject]) -> Void

it no longer throws that previous error but now when I use the completion block it throws a new error:

> Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[JSONObject]'

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.jsonObjectsArray = JSONObject.updateResultsDictionary(urlExtension: "/cities/basel-switzerland", completion: {JSONObject in

      self.practiceTableView.reloadData()


    })


  }
```

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense. Why does `updateResultsDictionary` create an empty array and pass that back in the closure? If there's only one item, you don't need an array. Or is this `getJSONData` calling its closure multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the `completion` parameter to be an array of `JSONObject`. It seems you mean to declare it as a closure that passes one parameter whose type would be an array of `JSONObject`.

```
static func updateResultsDictionary(urlExtension: String, completion: @escaping (_: [JSONObject]) -> Void) {
```

You also need to change how you call this method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    JSONObject.updateResultsDictionary(urlExtension: "/cities/basel-switzerland", completion: { (results) in
        self.jsonObjectsArray = results
        self.practiceTableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

And your call to:

```
completion(jsonDataArray)
```

needs to be moved to where `jsonDataArray` is actually being set. It needs to be called at the end of the completion block to the call to `getJSONData`.